# How to send an HTTP request for form submission with parameters

Tags: javascript

I have tried to send an HTPP request for form submission in JavaScript with parameters. It is in the browser console. It looks like this:

```
params,(My parameters...)
        some:some;
        some:some;
        some:some;
Header,
       asusaul;
Post,(the form submit)
```

Comment: Have you looked into ajax ? http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: Here is an excellent tutorial/reference for AJAX: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Answer (score 0):

You can use formdata to submit form in javascript.

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("username", "Groucho");
formData.append("accountnum", 123456); // number 123456 is immediately converted to a string "123456"

// HTML file input, chosen by user
formData.append("userfile", fileInputElement.files[0]);

// JavaScript file-like object
var content = '<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>'; // the body of the new file...
var blob = new Blob([content], { type: "text/xml"});

formData.append("webmasterfile", blob);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "http://foo.com/submitform.php");
request.send(formData);
```